# trying to modify json using jq, and need to get the whole json as output

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to modify , following json, and need to get whole json with changes as the output, but the command I use gives only the children object based on the filter I use , how to get the whole json as the output with the changes.(Note : I'm running this is shell)

```
command I use;

jq '.properties.basic.nodes_table | map(if (.node|test("^10[.]13[.]")) then .state="disabled" else . end)' data.json
```

data.json

```
    "properties": {
        "basic": {
        "nodes_table":[
             {
        "node":"10.13.248.254:61052",
        "state": "active"
             },
            {
        "node":"10.13.248.255:61052",
        "state": "active"
             },
            {
        "node":"10.54.247.228:61052",
        "state": "active"
            },
            {
        "node":"10.54.247.229:61052",
        "state": "active"
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Current output

```
[
  {
    "node": "10.13.248.254:61052",
    "state": "disabled"
  },
  {
    "node": "10.13.248.255:61052",
    "state": "disabled"
  },
  {
    "node": "10.54.247.228:61052",
    "state": "active"
  },
  {
    "node": "10.54.247.229:61052",
    "state": "active"
  }
]
```

expected output

```
{
    "properties": {
        "basic": {
        "nodes_table":[
             {
        "node":"10.13.248.254:61052",
        "state": "disabled"
             },
            {
        "node":"10.13.248.255:61052",
        "state": "disabled"
             },
            {
        "node":"10.54.247.228:61052",
        "state": "active"
            },
            {
        "node":"10.54.247.229:61052",
        "state": "active"
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```